# Sodium - reduce salt from a salty food?

Tags: running, weightlifting, weight-loss, diet, bodyweight-exercises

How to reduce sodium from canned foods?

Canned foods such as tuna contain protein but do contain a lot of sodium too.

Is there smart way to remove sodium from the food? Maybe by boiling or using 
some other technique?

[image]

Comment: sodium does not cause belly fat. It can lead to (very small) weight gains via water, but if this is your argument against it, you should really reconsider your position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least within the context of canned vegetables, [draining the liquid and rinsing the vegetables](https://www.bestfoodfacts.org/rinsing-canned-food/) yields a 9-40% reduction in sodium. Although, note that the US Department of Agriculture has also pointed out that [draining the can, or rinsing, can reduce the nutrient content](https://www.ars.usda.gov/ARSUserFiles/80400525/Articles/EB11_DrainedVeg.pdf), because you're dumping water-soluble vitamins that have migrated into the water.

Comment: Wait, you provide an answer, then, vote to close?

Comment: I changed my mind. I thought there was a fitness impact of the sodium.